# vb.net artificial scope

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, syntax, c#-to-vb.net

In VB.Net 4.0, I have situations where I need to repeat similar code, but due to the complexity of the code I won't be able to create subroutines to simplify.  I want to be able to declare variables in a block scope, go out of scope, then repeat.  My current method is to do something like this.

```
If True Then
  Dim A = ...
  Dim B = ...
  (Code using A & B)
End If
```

...And then repeat as much as I need.

This one works too...

```
Try
  Dim A = ...
  Dim B = ...
  (Code using A & B)
Finally
End Try
```

Otherwise I have to give each variable unique names...

```
Dim A1 = ...
Dim B1 = ...
(Code using A1 and B1)
Dim A2 = ...
Dim B2 = ...
(Code using A2 and B2)
```

...which makes repeating the code dangerous because I may forget to change a variable name as I am copying code.

You can do it in C#...

```
{
  int A = ...
  int B = ...
  (Code using A & B)
}
```

Is there a way in VB.Net to create a block this way?

Comment: you can use a with block, but that only allows one variable at a time, and doesn't nest intuitively. otherwise I won't say it doesn't exist, but i've been working with VB for a long time, and never seen any scope delimiters as you suggest.

Comment: I gather the type for A and B changes for each proposed repeating code block?  If so why would have want to keep the same names for the variables?  If the type doesn't change per repeating code block, then why not just declare the variables at the top of the method and re-use them?

Comment: @BlackMael: The type stays the same, but I want the values to go out of scope to prevent them from being reused by the next block.

Comment: Got me stumped. I'd probably go for the anwser by @EkoostikMartin but I am finding it difficult to understand that the code is too complex to break into subroutines but not too difficult to break into code blocks.  Do you use CodeRush/Refactor, Resharper or something similar to do the refactoring for you?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin:  The code is for a template that I am handing out to beginning programmers, so I can't rely on re factoring code.  The code is complex because it references a bunch of resource file locations and typed datasets with long namespaces.  The sub call got really big so I started creating variables to make it more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this answer on a Japanese site.

```
With Nothing
  Dim A = ...
  Dim B = ...
  (Code using A & B)
End With
```

from http://www.ilovex.co.jp/Division/ITD/archives/2007/11/with_nothing.html

> (Translated from Japanese) I think if we think about it, to use a With statement of whether it is
>   not a better.  Because, With statement is intended to be used in order
>   to omit the code, because it is not intended to associative processing
>   from the statement itself.

So the point is, the "With" statement doesn't really do anything other than shortcut contained code.  It does, however, create a unique scope.  This seems like it should be pretty light in the compiler.  While I would love to see some new statement like "Begin/End" this is what I will use from now on.

Comment: I doubt that many would need this _feature_ but the solution is ... elegant ;)

Comment: A brilliant solution to identify accidentally-used variables outside their intended scope

Answer (score 2):

There is no inherent block scope syntax in VB.Net, the most common way is the first example you gave in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is hacky hacky, but how about:

```
Do
  dim a
  dim b

  ...

loop while (false)
```

sort of the same as your if statement, but you get to use the false constant.

Comment: That is a different way, but I will always think that is a loop when I look at it.

Comment: @Carter - I purist would argue you are looping -- just only once.